# $new as a variable in php keyword

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a portal, in which I am working with news. Basically, I am planning to retrieve them from database and working with them. Is it safe to work with `news` ? Can I get trapped later by using a word `new`, because of being a keyword or something?

Comment: as long as $+keyword is set, no. Best thing to know more : test

Comment: Variable names (anything starting with `$`) do not get conflicted with reserved words. You can do `$class`, `$new`, `$function`.. without any conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, that's great news

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's both an advantage and a drawback to have the sigil `$` in PHP: there is no conflict with the keywords and you can directly inject your variables in a string (for example `"foo $bar"`) but you have to write one extra character each time.

It won't create conflicts with PHP a priori as I said, but beware if you're not also using SQL keywords, for example if you create a `long` attribute for a longitude.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a suffix such as $newsText etc, but once you have the "$" in front of the word, it is read as a variable.